# Access first X elements in a Class (Ruby / Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tested a couple of methods for printing the first 3 instances of my class for a Ruby on Rails application. I've already got the following working :

```
    <%@posts.each do |post| %>
            <div class ="post content" >
              <h2 class="title"><%=post.title%></h2>
                <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y")%></p>
                <p class="body"><%=post.body%></p>
            </div>
    <% end %>
```

But I'm trying to do the same thing but *only* printing the first 3 elements of the @posts variable.

.first(3) and .find(:id) haven't worked and I'm at a loss on how to iterate through the class variables.

Thanks.

Comment: how come `@posts.first(3).each` hasn't worked?

Comment: Not entirely sure, the first method isn't throwing an error but it's also not printing anything to the divs as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [take](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/take).

```
<% @posts.take(3).each do |post| %>
```

[first](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/first) works in a similar manner (but it orders by `id`), and should get the job done as well.

PS: You should consider moving this logic in the controller.

Comment: .take(n) works for me with each. Thank you! Solved my problem,

Answer (score 3):

If you only need 3 `posts` and don't require the rest anywhere in your view, then **filter them out in your controller** and don't query for unused models.

In your controller:

```
@posts = Post.limit(3)   # Post.where(x: 'y').limit(3)
```